# Preg_match address

Tags: php, preg-match

So i'm trying to preg_match an address in PHP.

It should be letters SPACE numbers and not numbers SPACE letters.
So, like this: Myplace 16.
The length of the numbers and letters doesn't matter, but they can't be mixed together.

I already tried this one but this one doens't check spaces:

```
if(preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]{5,}$/", $adres) === 0)
{
echo 'Address is wrong';
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So for example "abc 1/2/D efg"?

Comment: no more like abc 09, no numbers before any letters. It always has to end with numbers like a real adress

Comment: I see, I was reading *"letters SPACE numbers and not numbers SPACE letters"* wrong then. I'd be useful if you would supply some examples to make it unambiguous what you want.

Comment: If this is supposed to validate the street component of an address, have you cosidered addresses like "Bla Street 1a"? This is a common practice in (at least) Germany/Switzerland. Or something like "1st avenue" (common in at least USA), …

Comment: I actually didn't think about this! But for now I will use the preg_match @aleks gave me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you showed doesn't correspond at all to what you're trying to do.  For your purpose, you would do something like

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+\ +[0-9]+$/
```

This checks for at least one letter at the beginning of the string followed by 1 or more spaces followed by 1 or more digits, at which point the string must end.

Unless, of course, I misunderstand what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

I use 1 to capture a error (preg_match returns false, and a 0, no match)

```
if(1 !== preg_match('/^[a-z]*\ +\d*$/i', $address))
{
    echo 'Address is wrong';
}
```

This will match any character between a-z (case insensitive) between 0 and unlimited times, then match at least a space character, then any numbers between 0 and unlimited times.
If you need at least 1 letter and 1 number please change the `*` to a `+`